# Cannot read property '' of undefined with addEventListener, gsap and react

Tags: reactjs, gsap

I got a problem I try to have an animation with my cursor with gsap and react but I got an error 
`"TypeError: Cannot read property 'page' of undefined"`

If someone can help me It's would be nice. Thanks

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.page = React.createRef();
    this.cursor = React.createRef();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App" ref={this.page} >
        <div>hey</div>
        <div className="cursor" ref={this.cursor}></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const enterMouse = () => {
//some code
};

const moveMousePos = (e) => {
//some code
};

this.page.addEventListener('mouseenter', enterMouse);
this.page.addEventListener('mousemove', moveMousePos);

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your functions enterMouse moveMousePos are not properly scoped.
Right now they are outside your component block.
You need to move those inside your component.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I got an error "TypeError: this.page.addEventListener is not a function
"

Comment: @askemeline Try moving the `addEventListener`s inside of the component as well.

Comment: @askemeline The `addEventListener`s will need to be in `componentDidMount` lifecycle function